# MySQL Group By + Order

Tags: php, mysql, database, group-by

I've got a problem with grouping my rows.

Example Table

```
ID, GroupID, INFO, COUNTER
1, 123456, INFO, 21
2, 654321, INFO, 20
3, 123456, INFO, 30
4, 654321, INFO, 11
```

First of all, I'd like to display them with this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table 
GROUP BY GroupID 
ORDER BY COUNTER DESC 
LIMIT 0, 60
```

So it should display only one of group type. It does, but the order is not good. So I think it's not getting the right number of `counter` paired to the `GroupID`.

The right displayed result would be: (the main order selector has to be the `count`)

```
ID, GroupID, INFO, COUNTER
3, 123456, INFO, 30
2, 654321, INFO, 20
```

How should I solve?

Comment: GROUPID 123456 has two counters, 21, 30.  and two different IDs (1,3)  which would you want displayed the 30 and 3?  same for 654321 but since the counter is 20 on ID 2 it would be displayed with ID 2 and not 4?  (an example if your desired output would help)

Comment: What is the "right" number of counter paired to the GroupID anyway? You need to use an aggregate function since you're grouping, e.g. max(counter), min(counter), avg(counter) ... otherwise you cannot make sure of the extracted values.

Comment: I've added the right result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT tablename.* FROM tablename 
    WHERE tablename.COUNTER = 
(SELECT MAX(COUNTER) FROM tablename AS f WHERE f.GroupID = tablename.GroupID) 
    ORDER BY tablename.COUNTER DESC
```

**Edited :** This will get you the complete rows containing the max value of COUNTER for each GroupID, and order the final results by COUNTER desc.

Comment: WoW, it works. I just can't find out what it does lol! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: It queries the rows from `tablename` but constraining each `COUNTER` to be equal to the maximum possible value for the `GroupID` from the same row. The trick is done using an alias `f` of the table, you should learn that, very useful.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination! Have a great day!

Comment: Can I have a question! Do you have any way to make the query work / load faster? It really loads our Xeon :/

Comment: How many rows do you have in the table? And do you have all indexes properly set? (on ID, GroupID, and COUNTER)

Comment: At this moment I have ~2.000 items in the table, and it's going up every day with like 500.

Comment: This is a very small table, it should go fast. Do you know what indexes are, you didn't answer about that?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes. The same cols are indexed as you mentioned!

Comment: How long does the query take then? I doubt this should be "too heavy", but that also depends on how often you request it. Is it on a website ? You could also cache the results each time a row is added (or else, depending on your needs)..